# R codigo_função with()

Tags: r

O que significa esta linha de código?

```
with(epilepsy,by(seizures/timeadj,list(treat,expind),mean))
```

os dados são do pacote `faraway`.

Answer (score 5):

A função `with` é uma função de conveniência que permite que você acesse as colunas do `data.frame` sem ter que ficar repetindo o nome do `data.frame` a todo momento.

O código:

```
with(epilepsy, by(seizures/timeadj, list(treat,expind), mean))
```

É a mesma coisa de:

```
by(epilepsy$seizures/epilepsy$timeadj, list(epilepsy$treat, epilepsy$expind), mean)
```

Veja que sem o `with` você precisa repetir o nome do `data.frame` `epilepsy` toda vez que fizer referência a suas colunas.